# Can I implement two resource interfaces with one implementation in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, embedded-jetty

I have two JAX-RS resource interfaces:

```
@Path(value = "/api/foo")
public interface FooResource {
  @GET
  @Path(value = "{id}")
  public FooBar getFoo(final @PathParam(value = "id") String id);

@Path(value = "/api/bar")
public interface BarResource {
  @GET
  @Path(value = "{id}")
  public FooBar getBar(final @PathParam(value = "id") String id);
```

When I do be able to do an HTTP `GET` on `/api/foo/123` or on `/api/bar/123`. When calling `GET` on `/api/foo/123` I want it to do some preprocessing and then delegate to the same code as for on `/api/bar/123`.

So can I just make a resource service implementation that implements both of these interfaces, allowing me to share code?

```
public class FooBarResourceService implements FooResource, BarResource {
```

I just tried this with Jetty and RESTEasy, and it doesn't seem to work. Calling `GET` on `/api/bar/123` works, but calling `GET` on `/api/foo/123` gives me a `404`. So I split out and registered two service implementations `FooResourceService` and `BarResourceService` (with a lot of redundant contents), and both paths work. But it seems a shame to have so much duplicated code.

Is this not allowed, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Put the common code into a separate helper class and call it from both resources.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I know what I can do to work around this. My question is whether I'm forced to do the workaround. Does the JAX-RS specification allow this?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not allowed according to the [JAX-RS 2.0 specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339).

> **Chapter 3.6 Annotation Inheritance**
>
> JAX-RS annotations may be used on the methods and method parameters of
> a super-class or an implemented interface. Such annotations are
> inherited by a corresponding sub-class or implementation class method
> provided that the method and its parameters do not have any JAX-RS
> annotations of their own. Annotations on a super-class take precedence
> over those on an implemented interface. The *precedence over conﬂicting
> annotations deﬁned in multiple implemented interfaces is
> implementation speciﬁc*. Note that *inheritance of class or interface
> annotations is not supported*.

Which is somehow clear. If both of your interfaces are annotated with `@Path`, the implementing class would 'inherit' both annotations, so it were two resource classes in one. And it were not clear which of the resource methods belong to what resource class (i.e. to what `@Path` annotation).

Of course, in theorie this could be determined by inspecting the interfaces to see where the method declaration comes from, but this introduces unnecessary complexity (and there are lots of exceptional situations) just to allow dubious code.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 conflicting `@Path` annotations on the interfaces. How should this work? You also can't have two on one class.

The [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) points out (p. 19):

> The precedence over conﬂicting annotations deﬁned in multiple implemented interfaces is implementation speciﬁc. Note that inheritance of class or interface annotations is not supported.

Your example is working if you use the full path on method-level:

```
public interface FooResource {
  @GET
  @Path(value = "/api/foo/{id}")
  public FooBar getFoo(final @PathParam(value = "id") String id);
}

public interface BarResource {
  @GET
  @Path(value = "/api/bar/{id}")
  public FooBar getBar(final @PathParam(value = "id") String id);
}
```

Note that I needed to add `@Path("/")` on the implementing resource to make this work (RESTeasy 3.0.6.Final).

Comment: I don't see the conflict. I would think that the JAX-RS server would work from the interfaces, and mount "some implementing class" to the `/api/foo/{id}` path, and "some implementing class" to the `/api/bar/{id}` path. Why would the server care that "some implementing class" happened to be the same class? Calls to `/api/foo/{id}` get routed to `getFoo()`. Calls to `/api/bar/{id}` get routed to `getBar()`. Where is the conflict?

Comment: Seems like this is not the way they are doing it. Maybe they are checking if the resource-class or an implemented interface has a `@Path` annotation. Then they are finding two.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:
Assuming your web.xml looks like this:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would change your code to look similar to this:

```
@Path("/api")
public class FooBarResourceService implements FooResource, BarResource{
    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    public FooBar getFoo(final @PathParam(value = "id") String id){
        // do work to get a FooBar
        Foobar fb = new FooBar();
        return rb;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    public FooBar getBar(final @PathParam(value = "id") String id){
        // Call your implementation here 
        Foobar fb = new FooBar();
        return fb;
    }

}
```

This is of course assuming that you have annotated `FooBar` appropriately with JAXBAnnotations for XML response.

Comment: But these two interfaces do not have "the same method". How is `getFoo(...)` and `getBar(...)` the same?

Comment: My bad.. I thought they were the same .. guess I'm dyslexic.

Comment: I can't remember if you need /foo/{id} and /bar/{id}.. Been a while but try both ways